# How can I make a label on Form1 say "Hello" from form2?

Tags: c#

That's it. It's a dumb dumb (embarrassing!) question, but I've never used C# before, only C++ and I can't seem to figure out how to access a Label on my main form from a secondary form and change the text. If anybody can let me know real quick what to do I'd be so grateful!

BTW, I should really clarify. Sorry: I've got two separate .cs files that each look about like below. I was using the [Designer] in VS2008 to add in the label in Form1. When I type something like Form1.label1 it doesn't understand. The dropdown shows a list of methods and properties for Form1, but there's only about 7, like ControlCollection, Equals, MouseButtons, and a couple others... I can publicly define a variable in Form1 and that shows, but I don't know how to access the label...

```
namespace AnotherProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need a reference to an *instance* of the form. Imagine if you had two Form1 forms showing at the same time - what would you expect Form1.label to refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a reference to the instance of Form1 - for example, if it's Form1 which is constructing Form2, you might pass `this` in as a constructor parameter.

Then you'll need to either expose the label of Form1 via a property (or - ick! - a non-private field) or write a method/property which will set the text of the label. For example:

```
public class Form1 : Form 
{
    private Label label;

    // Construction etc as normal

    public string LabelText
    {
         get { return label.Text; }
         set { label.Text = value; }
    }

    public Form2 CreateForm2()
    {
        return new Form2(this);
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
        // Normal construction
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        form1.LabelText = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect. No wonder! I was still in the C++ mindset. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a reference to Form1 from Form2.   Then you need either a method or a property on Form 1 visible to Form2 that changes the label text to "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Public Class Form1
>     Inherits Form
>
>
>     Friend label1 As New Label
>
>
>     Public Sub openForm2()
>         Dim f As New Form2(Me)
>         f.Show()
>     End Sub
>
>
> End Class
>
>
> Public Class Form2
>     Inherits Form
>
>
>     Private _ref As Form1
>
>
>     Public Sub New()
>         _ref = Nothing
>     End Sub
>
>
>     Public Sub New(ByVal formRef As Form1)
>         _ref = formRef
>     End Sub
>
>
>     Public Sub accessLabel(ByVal setText As String)
>         If (_ref IsNot Nothing) Then
>             _ref.label1.Text = setText
>         Else
>             Throw New NullReferenceException("_ref is NULL")
>         End If
>     End Sub
>
>
> End Class
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that delegates is the most powerful option, besides having properties in a Form: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826AM/winformsdelegates.aspx

In the second form I define:

```
public delegate void AddItemDelegate(string item);
public AddItemDelegate AddItemCallback;
```

And from the form that opened it I write:

```
private void btnScenario2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FrmDialog dlg = new FrmDialog();
    //Subscribe this form for callback
    dlg.AddItemCallback = new AddItemDelegate(this.AddItemCallbackFn);
    dlg.ShowDialog();

}
private void AddItemCallbackFn(string item)
{

    lstBx.Items.Add(item);

}
```